# How to validate a form all fields without knowing field names in html

Tags: python, django

I want to validate a form where any field should not be blank. I don't know the name of the fields. The code is:

```
 <form action="/addproductgroupinsert_fun/" method="post" name="SForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    {% for id in ProductTypefeatureentryList %}
       <label for="{{id.Name}}">{{id.Name}}</label>
       <input id="{{id.Name}}" type="text"name="{{id.Name}}" />
    {% endfor %}
```

How can do this?

Comment: the code you posted is not javascript, jquery, or html, which are the only tags on this question. can you clarify what you have?

Comment: This code is belongs to django,doing this in django templates.

Comment: What specific type of validation are you looking for? Basic non-empty? Numeric? Text length?

Comment: @AngrySpartan "field should not be blank" - read the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, add a class to mark them as required. Then you can validate all of the elements with that class:

```
{% for id in ProductTypefeatureentryList %}
   <label for="{{id.Name}}">{{id.Name}}</label>
   <input class="required" id="{{id.Name}}" type="text"name="{{id.Name}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

in `validateForm()`:

```
$('.required').each(function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        // form is invalid
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider HTML-5 `data-val-*` attributes and have a look at jquery unobtrusive validation plugin. your inputs would look something like

```
 <form action="/addproductgroupinsert_fun/" method="post" name="SForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    {% for id in ProductTypefeatureentryList %}
       <label for="{{id.Name}}" data-val-required='true'>{{id.Name}}</label>
       <input id="{{id.Name}}" type="text"name="{{id.Name}}" data-val-required='true' />
    {% endfor %}
```

`data-val-required` is for telling unobtrusive js that feild's value is required. Most of the articles you would look on internet would link unobtrusive js with asp.net mvc but it is a client side library and can play with any server side technology. Furthermore, i have not tested the code and I think there is one more attribute for specifying the error message in case the value of the field is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

This runs through your list of inputs:

```
$('input').each(function() {
   //Do your validation
});
```